# Парсинг XML в Android

Tags: android, sax, dom

Подскажите, пожалуйста, мне необходимо распарсть простую XML'ку вида:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<result>
  <status code="200" />
   <building number="434" part="0" url="http://www.piccadillyrecords.com/mp3/Sum%2041%20-%20No%20Brains.mp3">Gu</building>
 </result>
```

Подскажите, как сделать это проще? Мб есть какой-то простой класс для париснга? Где-то видел аналог php'шной simplexml, но теперь найти не могу

Answer (score 3):

Я бы написал простейший парсер на основе SAX примерно так (написано на коленках, так что просьба помидорами не кидаться!)

```
factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
factory.setNamespaceAware(false);
xpp = factory.newPullParser();
StringReader sw=new StringReader(s); //s содержит ваш XML
xpp.setInput(sw); //подаем на вход парсера
int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT)
{
    if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) //начальный тег
    {
        inBuilding=false;
        if(xpp.getName().compareTo("status")==0)
            code = xpp.getAttributeValue(null, "code"); //читаем атрибут code
        else if(xpp.getName().compareTo("building")==0)
        {
            number = xpp.getAttributeValue(null, "number");
            part = xpp.getAttributeValue(null, "part");
            url = xpp.getAttributeValue(null, "url");
            inBuilding=true;
        }
    }
    else if(eventType==XmlPullParser.TEXT)
    {
        if(inBuilding) //если мы внутри тега building
            buildingValue=xpp.getText();
    }
    eventType=xpp.next();
}
```

Естественно, значения атрибутов, полей и проч. после прочтения надо куда-то складывать. Ну вы уж там сами дальше :)

Answer (score 0):

[XmlPullParser](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html)

> XML Pull Parser is an interface that defines parsing functionality...

Answer (score 0):

Почитайте тут: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/

Ещё вариант:

```
//вспомогательный метод - получает содержимое тэга
String getTagValue(String sTag, Element eElement) { 
    NodeList nlList = eElement.getElementsByTagName(sTag).item(0).getChildNodes();
    Node nValue = (Node) nlList.item(0);

    return nValue.getNodeValue();
}

void test() {
   File xmlFile = new File(PathToFile);

   DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
   DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

   Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
   doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

   doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName(); //имя корневого тэга
   NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("building"); //получаем все теги building
   for (int nodeIndex = 0; nodeIndex < nList.getLength(); temp++) { //пробегаем тэги
       Node nNode = nList.item(temp);
       if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
           Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
           getTagValue("building", eElement); //получить содержимое текущего тэга
           eElement.getAttribute("number"); //получить значение аттрибута
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

В Java много средств для работы с XML.

- [Работа с XML в Android](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/x-android/)
- [Использование XML и JSON с Android: Часть 1. Преимущества JSON и XML для Android-приложений](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/x-andbene1/)
- [Использование XML и JSON с Android: Часть 2. Создание гибридных Android-приложений с применением JSON](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/x-andbene2/)

Пример десериализации с помощью [Simple](http://simple.sourceforge.net/home.php)

```
Serializer s = new Persister();
Example e = s.read(Example.class, new File("example.xml"));
```